# Using Same AudioPlayer Again and Again

Tags: just-audio

I want to use the same `AudioPlayer` instance for each play operation to avoid reloading assets each time. How can I achieve this?

Currently, I've created an `AudioPlayer` instance like below.

```
AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();
await _player.setAsset("sounds/hit.mp3");
_player.play();
```

But after running the `_player.play()` function once, the sound no longer plays anymore on next invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoke _player.stop() before each play (reset the position).